# QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

Here is my two pojo fields

```
@ManyToMany
@Cascade(value = SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinTable(name = "catalogToCatalog",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parentId",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "childId",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))})
private List<Catalog> parents;

@Cascade(value = SAVE_UPDATE)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Catalog.class)
private List<Catalog> children;
```

How I could get data with named query like

```
"from Catalog c left join c.parents p " +
        "where p.parentId = :parentId";
```

?

```
 QueryException: could not resolve property: parentId of: com.x.model.Catalog [from com.x.model.Catalog c left join
```

Comment: Is 'parentId' a property or a column? because `@JoinColumn` use column names and not property names

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci it is a column name like here "SELECT parentid, childid
FROM "store".catalogtocatalog"

Comment: you have to use property names in HQL

Comment: thx! but how it should be done? if i not specify parentId and childId, they wil not be created in catalogToCatalog